# ImageMagick options in php Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

how do I execute following ImageMagick unix command in php OOP way using library Imagick?
`convert -density 2000 -antialias 20.eps -resize 200x200  20.png`
I read that to set `density` i need to call `setImageResolution`, but it doesn' work. I also read that it must be set before reading image, but then i get exception `Can not process empty Imagick object`
Also, how do I set antialias option?

Now I do this:

```
$I = new Imagick();
$I->readImage($src);
$I->setImageResolution(2400, 2400);
$I->resizeImage($width, $height, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0, true);
$I->writeImages($destination, true);
```

And image gets pixelated, but when I ran the unix command, image is nice and neat.

Comment: Use `setSize` instead of `setImageResolution`. `$I->setSize(200, 200);`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the image resolution needs to be done before reading the image.

```
$I = new Imagick();
//This is probably the right one
$I->setResolution(2400, 2400);
//$I->setImageResolution(2400, 2400);
$I->readImage($src);
```

And I the setXXXX and probably the functions to use before an image is loaded, rather than setImageXXX functions.....though the manual and ImageMagick is not particularly clear.